# ++ operator in JS. Why do I have to switch it around when using a variable and a '+'?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am learning JS right now. And I just learned the ++ operator. I remember from ruby that I can add a variable in there and it worked fine, but eventually I ran into an issue.

For example:

```
var num = 1;
var num2 = 3;

var newNum = num2+num;
```

If I console.log 'newNum' I get 4. If I switch my operator around to be like this:

```
var newNum = +num2num;
```

It does not work. Node freaks out on me!

So when I want to just change the 'num' variable I have to switch the order of things.

Ex:

```
var newNum = num+num2;
```

This is now working whereas before it did not.

My question is: Is there a better way to do this? Or a more consistent method? If not that's fine, I will just flip them around each time. I was just wondering.

Thanks!

Comment: + num2 num is not JS

Comment: Your question is very confusing. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Did not realize I needed a space either. Thanks for that. I will just remember to flip them around.

Comment: Yes, what does this have to do with ++?

Comment: @LeonidBeschastny I am trying to figure out why I have to flip the operator expression around for it to work depending on where it is compared to the variable I am trying to modify. Hopefully that helps! I am just trying to find a consistent manner other than flipping the order around.

Comment: The space allows JS to recognize you're talking about two different things. How could JS know otherwise?

Comment: This is 100% consistent, btw, and is the same across essentially all brace languages.

Comment: @ChadSchouggins Well in Ruby I could use +declaredVariable instead of ++ or +4 to increment values in a while loop or a for loop. Does this help you understand my dilemma?

Comment: @DaveNewton Ok thank you. This was the answer I was looking for! Just wanted to be sure there wasn't a little trick I could use. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`+` is an **infix** operator. That means, you put it **between** the things you want to add. Addition is **commutative**, which means that `a + b` is equal to `b + a`, all else being equal.

`+` is also available as a (unary) **prefix** operator, meaning you put it before **one** operand.

`++` is a completely different operator, the "increment" operator, that comes in both prefix and postfix flavors.

There is also the **addition assignment operator** `+=` , which takes a variable to be incremented on the left side, and a value to increment it by on the right side. Perhaps this is what you were looking for?

```
num += num2;
```

Read the docs. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators, or https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators.

Comment: Hey thanks a bunch! Now I know for sure. Did not realize this question would backfire. I was genuinely curious..

Comment: Do note that the whole "commutative" thing doesn't always apply in JavaScript ([] + {} and {} + []) ;)

Comment: @ChadSchouggins That's why I said "all else being equal" :-)

Comment: Ok cool. Now I learned a few more things than expected. Sweet!

Answer (score 1):

Javascript does not support polish notation when performing operations.

Comment: Gotcha. I will have to avoid doing that then!

Answer (score 0):

Javascript uses infix notation for any binary operators. The plus must be in between the operands of the expression.

Comment: As simple as that was, that's what I thought. Thanks for clearing it up.

Answer (score 0):

> If I console.log 'newNum' I get 4. If I switch my operator around to be like this:
>
> ```
>     var newNum = +num2num;
> ```

That's because the variable num2num does not exist and therefore cannot be evaluated.

As for your original question, I believe you are referring to **Polish notations** which are not supported in JavaScript the way they are supported in Python.

In JavaScript, `++` is a prefix/suffix for operators.

`++` is used for increment.

Comment: Thanks! I was just curious as to why it worked in some instances and not in others. This explains it very well.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you misunderstand what the + and the ++ operators do.

```
var newNum = num2+num;
```

This line works because you are simply adding 2 numbers. As you can see, the + operator is used in an infix notation, where the operator is between the 2 operands.

```
var newNum = + num2 num;
```

The notation for this line is called postfix notation. Given that Javascript does not support it as is, you can see why it throws an error. It is looking for the an operand before the + and another after num2.

You mentioned the ++ operator. What that does, as torazaburo said, is that it is an increment operator with both a post and prefix version, but it doesn't need 2 operands. For example:

```
num = 7;
console.log(num++)
```

The above code will print out 7, then increment num to 8.

```
num = 7;
console.log(++num)
```

The above code will increment num first, then print out the incremented num, 8.